# How does healing (not external) work?

Tags: battlefield-1

You take some damage and after some time, your life starts regenerating at some uncertain *(for me)* speed but...

1. Do I regenerate more life **standing still** than **running** or **jumping**?
2. Do all classes have the same **regeneration pattern**?
3. Is this pattern affected by **gas grenades** in any way?
4. Is the speed or the amount of regeneration **based on my actual HP**?

So far, I can only say that when playing *Sniper*, it seems to be working the same way all the time but I haven't actually payed enough attention to it yet.